# Disable logging during manage.py test?

Tags: python, django, logging

I utilize the standard python logging module.  When I call `python manage.py test` I'd like to disable logging before all the tests are ran.  Is there a signal or some other kind of hook I could use to call logging.disable?  Or is there some other way to disable logging when `python manage.py test` is ran?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I know of is to edit `manage.py` itself... not very elegant, of course, but at least it should get you to where you need to be.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought of that (...well obviously).  Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

There is actually a much better way to do so, with [django-nose](https://github.com/jbalogh/django-nose) there is a kwarg:

Just run:

```
./bin/manage.py test --logging-clear-handlers
```

Comment: Indeed, I hadn't specified, but you need django-nose for that : https://github.com/jbalogh/django-nose and https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html?highlight=#cmdoption--logging-clear-handlers

Answer (score 11):

Easiest thing I've used:

```
import logging

class MyTestClass(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        logging.disable(logging.CRITICAL)
```

This requires no editing, patching, extra installs, and so on. All logging is turned completely off.

Answer (score 9):

As an easy alternative, you can disable logging when running tests in your settings file like this:

```
if 'test' in sys.argv:
    logger.removeHandler(handler)
    logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

Answer (score 4):

I prefer run tests with separate settings_test.py, where I can remove unnecessary applications, middleware and other stuff that I don't need during testing. And I can disable logging output here also by this way:

```
from settings import *
import logging

# direct all logging output to nowhere
class NullHandler(logging.Handler):
    def emit(self, record):
        pass
logging.getLogger().addHandler(NullHandler())
```

Answer (score 1):

I patched [test_extensions](http://github.com/schinckel/django-test-extensions) to also do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [django-nose](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-nose), then you can add the below snippet to your `settings.py` file to disable logging output when running `./manage.py test`

```
NOSE_ARGS = [
    '--nologcapture'
]
```